# What is the equivalent of from_days() of mysql in sql server?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have to do the database migration. I came across `to_days()` and `from_days()` functions in `MySQL`. I found the `datediff()` as the equivalent of `to_days()` which gives the difference between two dates. I searched for the equivalent of `from_days()` which returns the date when the number of days is given as a parameter but could not find the appropriate answer. Can anyone please help me with it?

Comment: Do you mean [DATEADD()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: Is Dateadd? The function you want

Comment: Right! Thankyou so much.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Can you please move your comment to Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would almost never be using `from_days()` by itself.  The following is the exact equivalent (at least for dates in the modern era):

```
select dateadd(day, 730669 - 693961, 0)
```

However, `from_days()` is usually used as some part of a date calculation.  The typical equivalent would be some combination of `dateadd()` and `datediff()`.